# How to assign a value to a null based on a unique identifier in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, null, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to assign a string to a null category based on the ID column. What I want to do is replace the nulls with the sales rep based on ID. I don't necessarily need to overwrite the nulls, adding a column with the adjusted sales names works too. I was thinking maybe using a case group by based on the unique ID but I have had no luck. I have a table with this type of structure:

Sample Data:

```
ID            SalesRep      Amount  
123           Steve         50.00  
123           Steve         100.00  
123           Steve         150.00   
123           NULL          200.00

456           Dave          25.00  
456           Dave          75.00  
456           Dave          500.00   
456           NULL          300.00
```

Expected Result:

```
ID            SalesRep      Amount  
123           Steve         50.00  
123           Steve         100.00  
123           Steve         150.00   
123           Steve         200.00

456           Dave          25.00  
456           Dave          75.00  
456           Dave          500.00   
456           Dave          300.00
```

Comment: Please show us your expected result as well. Also, what have you attempted so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Finally: which RDBMS are you using? Please add the relevant tag to your question: oracle, sql-server, mysql...?

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? We need both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(SalesRep,
                max(SalesRep) over (partition by id) as imputed_ SalesRep
               )
from t;
```